# Having finite knowledge, could we prove that God doesn't exist?

Tags: theology, paradox, existence-of-god

It seems to me that in order to prove that God does not exist, we need to be like the God himself: the supreme being, infinite in the knowledge of the universe. If my logic is correct, that sounds like a paradox.

Comment: It is hard to assert that we can prove either G's existence or G's non-existence... Having said that, the fact that we cannot prove G's non-existence does not mean that we have proved G's existence.

Comment: In principle a *proof* is a human "construct"; thus, it must be finite.

Comment: 1. If we proved that something does not exist, it means it cannot exist. Or, by logic, we cannot have both "A" and "Not A" relations true at the same time.  
2. Infinity is also a human construct, and it's infinite. No?

Comment: "Infinity is also a human construct, and it's infinite. " Assume so: thus, we - finite humans - have a grasp of the "infinite" concept (see mathematics). Thus, we have also a grasp of the concept of an infinite God and we are finite. In conclusion: we can "manage" concepts involving infinite.

Comment: Thus, in principle, how a (human) proof about the **non**-existence of an infinite being will be different from the proof about the existence of [infinitely many prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem)?

Comment: What is crooked cannot be made straight; what is not there cannot be counted. ©Ecclesiastes

Comment: No. Proof only relates to the domain of valid inferences of defined abstractions, ie logic & math, so not pertaining to existence which is only determined observationally. What we can say is 'God Is Not A Good Theory' https://youtu.be/ew_cNONhhKI (physicist Sean Carroll's talk on that topic)

Comment: Depends on what "prove" means. If it means absolute certainty then we cannot "prove" anything at all, not even mathematical theorems. After all, our logic can be faulty. If it means something more humanly relevant, like proving some theory experimentally, then why not? Physicists plausibly proved that aether does not exist, so why not God? Or if we prove logically that a notion of God is self-contradictory then we will prove that *such* God does not exist.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If a particular formulation/definition of God entails a logical contradiction then that would be a way to prove that that God does not exist.

Comment: ???............

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  One could formulate a definition of God that is internally logically inconsistent.  Someone else could find a finite proof to demonstrate that inconsistency.  That would show that the god proposed by the first person cannot exist (despite being "infinite" in one or more aspects).

Comment: Please do not post comments as answers.

Comment: @Conifold this is an answer in that it provides a finite way to disprove various kinds of proposed gods, whether those gods involved “infinite” properties of one kind or another.